# C# DataGridView get selected row number Exception

Tags: c#, datagridview

Im trying to get the currently selected row in a `datagridview` inside and int, but all the examples i find even here on this website, it always gives me error of index being outside the bounds, so i used the if statement to check is there is any rows selected at all but it just only returns me -1, no matter what i select, which i just don't get why it doesn't work for me.

```
    private void mainTableDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = -1;
        if (mainTableDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            index = mainTableDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        }
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(index);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you assigning "int index" as -1?

Comment: Whats wrong with your code it is working fine.There should be error in loading data in your gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: he wants the row not the SelectedCell

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    Int32 selectedRowCount = mainTableDataGridView.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
    if (selectedRowCount > 0)
    {
        index = mainTableDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index.ToString();
    }
    textBox1.Text = index;
```